# RecyclerView Items loosing MATCH_PARENT setting after clicking on EditText Field

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Hello I have a very weird problem that it drives me crazy. I have a DialogFragment and inside that a RecyclerView. I have a custom adapter for my RecyclerView and a custom XML layout for both the DialogFragment and the RecyclerView Adpater.

When I open the dialog the view is just fine. As it should be.

[image: Normal behavior when dialog opens]

The problem appears when I click inside the EditText Field (the yellow box in picture) and the on screen keyboard pops up. Then for some reason the entire layout messes and it behaves as I defined it as WRAP_CONTENT.

[image: Problematic behavior after clicking on the TextEdit field]

I have no idea why is that happening. My code seems right and after looking up on other similar questions the code is right to my eyes.

This is the RecyclerView custom layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/packitemnoField"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_barcode_small"
        android:drawablePadding="4dp"
        android:paddingStart="4dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:paddingEnd="4dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="0062020512845" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/qtyDescTV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:text="@string/tweightLabel"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/packDescField" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/RemainsDescTV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:text="@string/weightLabel"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/qtyDescTV"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/qtyDescTV" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/thWeightField"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:textColor="@color/darkGrey"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/qtyDescTV"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/qtyDescTV"
        tools:text="9999 kg." />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/weightField"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:textColor="@color/successGreen"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/qtyDescTV"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/RemainsDescTV"
        tools:text="9999 kg." />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/packDescField"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:textColor="@color/od_color1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/packitemnoField"
        tools:text="ALBIO / ΠΡΟΦΙΛ ΠΕΛΑΤΗ" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/kgIcon"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:tint="@color/darkGrey"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/newWeightInput"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/newWeightInput"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_weight" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/newWeightInput"
        android:layout_width="69dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border_qty"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="4"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorSecondaryVariant"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/kgIcon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="9999" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/packDateField"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:text="26/03/2020"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/newWeightLbl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:text="@string/newWeight"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/newWeightInput"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/newWeightInput"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/newWeightInput" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And this is the code in the onCreateViewHolder method in the adapter

```
@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rvr_package, parent, false);
    return new PackagesViewHolder(view);
}
```

Here is tha DialogFragment layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/updateWeightBtn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="@string/update"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/closeBtn"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/closeBtn" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/closeBtn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:text="@string/close"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/packagesRecyclerView" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/packagesRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Add the dialogfragment XML layout

Comment: @MatPag ok, I added the dialogFragment layout

Comment: 1) RecyclerView should have wrap_content height, 2) Check if you have some `android:windowSoftInputMode` in your manifest, if yes try removing them from the host activity. 3) In RecyclerView row layout using so many fixed width and height is always dangerous and can lead to strange problems, better if you use percentage values with `app:layout_constraintWidth_percent` to keep fixed aspect while using wrap_content for EditText and TextViews height

Answer (score 1):

you can try add to your constraintLayout of DialogFragment this line :

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/packagesRecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```